# Why PyCharm reports fake warning to decorated methods? What is the pythonic way of defining decorator for methods?

Tags: python, pycharm, decorator, lint

**Issue description**

Consider the following scenario:

- I have a class "Speaker" which is able to deliver speech.
- Some methods, e.g. "speak", effectively deliver the speech.
- Before delivering the speech, we need to turn on the mic, and after the speech, we need to turn off.
- To avoid doing this in every method which delivers the speech, I created a decorator to turn the mic on and off.

It is an imaginary example. My real code is about connect to and disconnect from database.

Code:

```
def use_mic(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):  # [3]
        self.turn_on_mic()  # [2] Method "turn_on_mic" is called, it is not a method of "str"
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.turn_off_mic()  # [2]

    return wrapper


class Speaker:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.mic_on = False

    @use_mic
    def speak(self, message):
        print("[%s speaks] %s" % (self.name, message))

    def turn_on_mic(self):
        print("Turn on microphone")
        self.mic_on = True

    def turn_off_mic(self):
        print("Turn off microphone")
        self.mic_on = False

    def greet(self):
        self.speak('Good morning my neighbours')  # [1] Lint warning here, because [2]


john = Speaker('John')
john.greet()
```

The code runs normally, but PyCharm reports the following lint warning:

[image]

PyCharm apparently regards the str parameter passed at [1] as the 1st parameter "self" at [3], and warns "no such attribute" based on [2]. But "Python passes the instance as the 1st parameter of a method when it is called with <object>.<method> or self.<method>" is a common sense.

**My question**

1. Why does PyCharm misunderdand the code?
2. Is it a bug of PyCharm's default lint tool, or did I write non-pythonic code?
3. What is the pythonic way of writing such code?
4. When I change [3] to the following code, the warning disappeared, but is it the pythonic way?

code:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):  # [2]
    self = args[0]
```

I'm using PyCharm 2021.1.3 (Community Edition) and Python 3.7.5

Comment: That is not just warning, **that's error** and I don't think you can even run that code since `wrapper` takes at least one parameter`self`, so `*args, **kwargs` will be empty because of `self.speak('Good morning my neighbours')` and `method(*args, **kwargs)` will throw error saying positional `message` argument is missing because it was already used as `self` for the wrapper but  `def speak(self, message)` expects it.

Comment: "The code runs normally" – no, no it doesn't. I'm running this on Python 3.9 and I get "TypeError: speak() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'". You would need `method(self, *args, **kwargs)` for it to work.

Comment: @ThePyGuy sorry I made a mistake, just add "self" when calling the method

Comment: @AKX sorry I made a mistake, just add "self" when calling the method

Comment: Whether your code is "pythonic" or not, this looks like a bug in PyCharm. Have you tried reporting this to JetBrains? As to *why*, there is no accounting for bugs.

Comment: There are known bugs in PyCharm regarding the typing of decorators, see e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12411 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40071

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd use a context manager for this sort of thing. They're easy to implement with the [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator (which is well-supported by PyCharm too).

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


class Speaker:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.mic_on = False

    @contextmanager
    def using_mic(self):
        self.turn_on_mic()
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            self.turn_off_mic()

    def speak(self, message):
        with self.using_mic():
            print("[%s speaks] %s" % (self.name, message))

    def turn_on_mic(self):
        print("Turn on microphone")
        self.mic_on = True

    def turn_off_mic(self):
        print("Turn off microphone")
        self.mic_on = False

    def greet(self):
        self.speak('Good morning my neighbours')


john = Speaker('John')
john.greet()
```